# How to instruct Android Studio to use a class in desire library (2 libraries having the same class)

Tags: android, gradle, duplicates

Basically I inherited an ancient project and they asked me to compile it with a modified version of the `android.jar` of platform-17. Problem is, the people originally in charge of it put a lot of other libraries into this `android.jar` (support v4, v7,...). Now if I want to use the `FragmentManager` class of the support library which is compiled by this

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'`

... I can't, because the `android.jar` already contains that class. The reason I want to use the class in the support library is because the `android.jar`'s `FragmentManager` lacks some of the methods which are currently being used in this ancient project. How can I instruct Android Studio to use the version of `FragmentManager` inside the support library instead of `android.jar`?

Comment: Why do you want to use an old modified android.jar?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I don't. The customer modified `android.jar` to add more functionality to it. Now they asked me to compile the project (which is previously compiled with sdk 22) with it.